# Nodejs .ini module (variable names start with a number)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ini

.ini file:

```
[1]
10X=true

[2]
10X=true
```

node.js :

```
var mS = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/XXX/MS.ini', 'utf-8'));
console.log(mS.1.10X);
```

I am using : `var ini = require('ini');` module's link here : https://www.npmjs.org/package/ini
My .ini files variable names start with number so node.js give me an error :

[image]

I have too many logs in .ini file, so i can not change variable names. 
Are there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to use this syntax

```
console.log(mS[1]['10X']);
```